# Input strings before switch statement & compare strings in c using switch statement

Tags: c, string, switch-statement

I am a student who are willing to learn c. My question is, user need to input a shape name and that shape name should go through switch statement. But I couldn't do that. Because I don't know how to pass strings to the switch statement. So can someone help me? I'll add my code for reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int h,w,r,l,area;
char shape[8];

printf("Please select a shape = ");
scanf("%s",&shape);

switch(shape[8]){
case 'circle':
    printf("Enter value for radius = ");
    scanf("%d",&r);

    area = 3.14*r*r;

    printf("Area of circle is = %d",area);
    break;
case 'square':
    printf("Enter value for width = ");
    scanf("%d",&w);

    area = w*w;

    printf("Area of square is = %d",area);
    break;
case 'rectangle':
    printf("Enter value for width = ");
    scanf("%d",&w);
    printf("Enter value for height = ");
    scanf("%d",&h);

    area = w*h;

    printf("Area of rectangle is %d",area);
    break;
case 'triangle':
    printf("Enter value for length = ");
    scanf("%d",&l);
    printf("Enter value for height = ");
    scanf("%d",&h);

    area = 1/2*l*w;

    printf("Area of triangle is = %d",area);
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid Shape");

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I think you will have to use `if` `else if` `else` ladder if you want to use strings as case labels, switch wont allow that

Comment: You don't really want a `switch()` statement to work with multiple strings. What you want is a lookup-table (an array of strings) containing the valid inputs. After you get an input from the user, loop over the array of strings comparing the input with each string, if a match is found `return 1;` (for true), otherwise `return 0;` (for false). That is probably the simplest way to go. If you had thousands of entries to compare against, then a hash-table would be in order.

Comment: @sravs Appreciate for your answer. But I want to do this using switch.

Comment: Is determining a number from the input an option? I.e. first do the comparing with `if`s, determine the number of a possibility and then go on with a swicth on that number. If that is not an option then many programmers will be convinced that what you are trying is impossible and ask you to clarify why you are convinced that what you are trying is possible. If a teacher is involved please quote the whole assigment, maybe you have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `switch()` is not the recommended way to handle this -- but you can do it. You will create a lookup-table (array of string literals of the valid shapes) and when you are checking if the user-input is a valid shape, you will save the index that corresponds to the valid shape and pass the index as the `switch()` variable. Then your cases will be integer values and you can take the appropriate action.

For example, you can create a simple lookup-table with:

```
/* lookup-table (array of pointers to string-literals) */
const char *shapes[] = { "circle", "square", "rectangle", "triangle" };

/* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NSHAPES (int)(sizeof shapes / sizeof *shapes)
```

Where `NSHAPES` is the number of shapes in your `shapes` array (you could just use `4`, but avoid hardcoding numbers ... *MagicNumbers*...)

Then you can create a simple function to loop over the array comparing the shape entered by the user with each of the shapes in your lookup-table, returning the index if found, or `-1` if not found, e.g.

```
/* function to validate shape is one of the valid shapes */
int validshape (const char *shape)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NSHAPES; i++)           /* loop over each shape */
        if (strcmp (shape, shapes[i]) == 0)     /* compare shape with shapes[i] */
            return i;                           /* return index if found */
    
    return -1;                                  /* return -1 if no match found */
}
```

Then in `main()`, you take the user-input and simply pass the string to the function and validate, e.g.

```
    int shape = -1;
    ...
        shape = validshape (line);              /* get shape index (-1 if none) */
        if (shape != -1)                        /* check index is valid  */
            break;                              /* (break loop if valid) */
        /* otherwise handle error, show allowed */
        fputs ("  error   : invalid input.\n", stderr);
```

With the valid index in `shape`, you can then `switch(shape)`, e.g.

```
    fputs ("\nvalid : ", stdout);
    switch (shape) {
        case 0: puts (shapes[0]); break;
        case 1: puts (shapes[1]); break;
        case 2: puts (shapes[2]); break;
        case 3: puts (shapes[3]); break;
        default: fputs ("oops -- shouldn't get here\n", stderr);
    }
```

You can update each of the cases to handle your arithmetic.

The full version (taking user input with `fgets()` so new C-programmers don't fall into the many pitfalls associated with taking user-input with `scanf()`, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* lookup-table (array of pointers to string-literals) */
const char *shapes[] = { "circle", "square", "rectangle", "triangle" };

/* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NSHAPES (int)(sizeof shapes / sizeof *shapes)
#define MAXC 1024

/* simple function to show allowed shapes */
void showallowed (void)
{
    fputs ("  allowed :", stdout);              /* output prefix */
    for (int i = 0; i < NSHAPES; i++)           /* loop over each shape */
        printf (" %s", shapes[i]);              /* output shape */
    putchar ('\n');                             /* tidy up with newline */
}

/* function to validate shape is one of the valid shapes */
int validshape (const char *shape)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NSHAPES; i++)           /* loop over each shape */
        if (strcmp (shape, shapes[i]) == 0)     /* compare shape with shapes[i] */
            return i;                           /* return index if found */
    
    return -1;                                  /* return -1 if no match found */
}

int main (void) {
    
    char line[MAXC];                            /* buffer to hold all user-input */
    int shape = -1;
    
    while (1) { /* loop continually */
        fputs ("\nenter shape: ", stdout);      /* output prompt for shape */
        if (!fgets (line, MAXC, stdin))         /* validate user input */
            return 1;
        line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;         /* trim \n from end of line */
        shape = validshape (line);              /* get shape index (-1 if none) */
        if (shape != -1)                        /* check index is valid  */
            break;                              /* (break loop if valid) */
        /* otherwise handle error, show allowed */
        fputs ("  error   : invalid input.\n", stderr);
        showallowed();
    }
    
    fputs ("\nvalid : ", stdout);
    switch (shape) {
        case 0: puts (shapes[0]); break;
        case 1: puts (shapes[1]); break;
        case 2: puts (shapes[2]); break;
        case 3: puts (shapes[3]); break;
        default: fputs ("oops -- shouldn't get here\n", stderr);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/validshapes

enter shape: apples
  error   : invalid input.
  allowed : circle square rectangle triangle

enter shape: squares
  error   : invalid input.
  allowed : circle square rectangle triangle

enter shape: rectangle

valid : rectangle
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately C doesn't support passing strings in case statements, so to avoid this you can either use if-else with `strcmp()` or assign each shape with a number and then pass it to the switch statement.